# What's the benefit of converting Firefall crystite to credits?

Tags: firefall

I've been playing the Firefall beta for a while now, and have amassed a large amount of crystite. I read in the patch notes that the new currency is going to be called "Credits" and you can convert crystite into credits (with a daily conversion limit).

However, when I logged into the game, I found that my repair costs were charged in crystite and not credits.

So I'm confused. If credits are the new currency, why would I have to pay for repairs in crystite? Should I convert all of my crystite to credits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credits are currently used for Multiple reasons:

1. You can use them for self revive out in the field
2. They can remove modules from sockets in items
3. They are used in the Player Marketplace for equipment and other items.
4. You can exchange them for RedBeans in a player driven economy (you set buying/selling prices)
5. Arcporting (fast travel) between SIN towers in Accord control

Converting all of your Crystite to credits is probably a bad idea as Crystite is still a main component in research/crafting, repairs, and purchasing goods from NPCs.

[Source and more information here](http://www.firefallthegame.com/news/path-to-launch-blog-6-introducing-credits)